# Python: Find the equation of my line, Logit

Tags: python, math, logistic-regression, equation, mlogit

I have some data that, when plotted, is looking like it is showing similarities to the LOGIT function. However, I need the equation of this line and I am struggling to find a package/function in Python to help me with this! Below is a screenshot of the graph. I have a load of X,Y data and I need the full equation of this line.

Every time I try and research this I am just pointed towards using logistic regression, however i'm convinced there must be a function in which I can input my data and comfortably receive an equation/coefficients for an equation in the output.

Sorry guys as I'm asking for whereabouts of a package I can't really provide my workings so far, because there are no workings thus far unfortunately.

Thanks all

[image]

Comment: If you already know the model, why do you need a function to tell you the model?

Comment: you make a very good point, I actually don't know why i thought i NEEDED the equation haha. Brain = mush. Still IF I didn't have all the data I needed to hand and still wanted the equation... how would I do it?